# SharePoint online OAuth2 token invalid_scope

Tags: azure, sharepoint, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get a Bearer token for my registered Azure AD-App to read all my sharepoint sites via API

I followed the guides from microsoft to a) [grant permissions for the app](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-user-consent) and b [get myself a token](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/graph/auth-v2-service#4-get-an-access-token)

so I now a) have all required permissions:
[image]
and b) received a token when using the scope `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`

So here is my issue: when I try to get a token for lets say `https://microsoft.sharepoint-df.com/Sites.Read.All`:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token

Body:x-www-form-urlencoded
client_id={appId}
scope=https://microsoft.sharepoint-df.com/Sites.Read.All
client_secret={secret},
grant_type=client_credentials
```

all I get in return is an error:

```
"error": "invalid_scope",
"error_description": "AADSTS70011: The provided request must include a 'scope' input parameter. The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope https://microsoft.sharepoint-df.com/Sites.ReadWrite.All is not valid.\r\nTrace ID: ...\r\nCorrelation ID: ...\r\nTimestamp: 2019-06-09 07:35:21Z",
"error_codes": [
    70011
],
```

Am I doing something wrong? I also tried the scope `https://{{tenantName}}.sharepoint.com/Sites.Read.All`

Comment: Share your full token request sample.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I did so

Comment: As you permitted your grant for share point on  your app so you needn't to set as scope for  `scope=https://microsoft.sharepoint-df.com/Sites.Read.All` you can set your `scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` your token would contains the permission for `Sites.Read.All`. If you [Decode](https://jwt.io/) your token [here](https://jwt.io/) you would Seen. If you still have any problem just let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using client credentials flow to get the access token. The scope must be

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

> The value passed for the scope parameter in this request should be the
>   resource identifier (application ID URI) of the resource you want,
>   affixed with the .default suffix. For the Microsoft Graph example, the
>   value is https://graph.microsoft.com/.default.  This value tells the
>   Microsoft identity platform endpoint that of all the direct
>   application permissions you have configured for your app, the endpoint
>   should issue a token for the ones associated with the resource you
>   want to use.

If you must use the specific scope like `https://microsoft.sharepoint-df.com/Sites.Read.All` You can use [auth code grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to get the access token.