# SharePoint Access token has two different scope values for tenants

Tags: azure-active-directory, sharepoint-rest-api, microsoft-graph-api

when I decode SharePoint access token for Tenant A and B it shows as below
for the tenant A

```
"scp": "AllSites.FullControl User.Read User.ReadBasic.All"
```

for the tenant B

```
"scp": ".1f7f4061-caa1-44c4-b29a-6d877e9a5211"
```

are there any possible reasons to this kind of result for different tenants where i am expecting Teanat A result.

my token request call is similar to this

```
                { "grant_type", "authorization_code" },
                 { "client_id", azureConfig.ClientId },
                 { "client_secret", azureConfig.ClientSecret },
                 { "scope", "https://123435350365.sharepoint.com/.default"},
                 { "redirect_uri","url" },
                 { "code", code }
```

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the scopes successfully in both tenants.***

I used the below **parameters** for both the tenants and got the access token for SharePoint successfully:

[image]

After decoding the token, I got the **`scope`** for both tenants successfully like below:

[image]

- Please check the **`scope`** you are giving for `Tenant B` and verify whether your tenant has access to SharePoint API or not.
- After decoding the token for `Tenant B` please check the **`aud`** and **`iss`** claims are valid or not.
- Please **note** that value for the SharePoint Online Tenant Id may vary for each Tenant.
- Make sure if you are giving permissions for Microsoft Graph then change the scope to `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`.

*If still the issue persists, try to raise [**Azure Support Ticket**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/options/).*

You can **refer** the below links to get some pointer to resolve the issue:

[azure - SharePoint online OAuth2 token invalid_scope - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56512878/sharepoint-online-oauth2-token-invalid-scope)

[How to access SharePoint Online data using Postman - REST API and Bearer token](https://code2care.org/sharepoint/how-to-access-sharepoint-online-data-using-postman-rest-graph-api-oauth)

Comment: is there any reason that it returns  unusual value for the scope such as "scp": ".1f7f4061-caa1-44c4-b29a-6d877e9a5211"   ?